# Pipes and arguments in python

Tags: python, io, pipe

I'm new to using pipes and I/O in python, and I've been using `sys.stdin.readlines()` from a file.

How do you read in an additional argument?
For example:

```
more input.txt | python program.py 200
```

I want to store that '200' in as a variable (int) in my program to use.

My attempt:

```
number = int(sys.argv[1])
```

For testing purposes I just typed

```
print number
```

but I didn't get the '200'.

---

Better explanation:

I have two files, 'test.txt' and 'test.py'

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
line = ""
for n in [line for line in sys.stdin.readlines()]:
    print n
```

When running

```
$ more test.txt | python test.py
```

it will print out

```
asdfsdf 200

sldkfjs 100

kljslkd 300
```

My goal is to just print out the line with the number I pass as an argument

My attempt:

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
number = int(sys.argv[1])
line = ""
for n in [line for line in sys.stdin.readlines()]:
    if n.split()[1] == number:
        print n
```

n.split()[1] should be the number from every line in the file correct? 
When running

```
$ more test.txt | python test.py 200
```

What I want to return is:

```
asdfsdf 200
```

But instead it's blank...

Comment: Looks and works right for me. I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: @Scott Carpenter sorry about that, I've updated the question with a better example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't replicate your problem.

This is my file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

number = int(sys.argv[1])
print number
```

Being run from command line with `more input.txt | python program.py 200` and the output is 200.

You could try `print str(sys.argv)` to investigate exactly what is in sys.argv

Comment: sorry, I've created a test situation and updated it in my question.